# In Go, how can I make a generic function with slices?

Tags: go, go-reflect

Let's say I want to write a function that finds a value in a slice

I intuitively want to write:

```
func find(s []interface{}, f func(interface{})bool) int {
    for i, item := range s {
        if f(item) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

however I don't manage to do this with Go. I could have an interface with

```
Len() int
Value(int) interface{}
...
```

and this would work but in my real code things are more complicated (I need to do slices[from:end] etc), append, ... etc and if I redefine all this in an interface I end up having a lot of code. Is there a better way?

Comment: The answer would be generics, but go doesn't do generics. So effectively you use reflection, write *n* find_[type] functions or walk around with interfaces everywhere. It's just not enjoyable in go so far.

Comment: What is going into the Array? Are they any arbitrary values, or are they specific types that need to be compared?

Comment: @squint the arrays are "standard". I have an array []A and an array of []B (all structs, not interfaces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as all of the answers here were written before go added generics, I'll add how you would implement this in go1.18+

Note, however, that as of go1.21, there is a `slices` package that contains many helpful, generic slice functions.

This is the implementation of `IndexFunc` straight from the standard library

```
// IndexFunc returns the first index i satisfying f(s[i]),
// or -1 if none do.
func IndexFunc[S ~[]E, E any](s S, f func(E) bool) int {
    for i := range s {
        if f(s[i]) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Notice how the function uses the type parameters `[S ~[]E, E any]` instead of just `S []any`. The difference is due do how slices are typed in go. Just like how you can't assert a slice of one type to a slice of another even if it's possible to assert the elements (ex. `[]int{}.([]any)` is invalid even though `int` satisfies `any`), you can't use an `[]int` as a parameter of type `S` if `S` is constrained to `[]any`.

Instead, it uses `S ~[]E` to constrain `S` to be a slice with elements of type `E`, where `E` can be any type. Additionally, this allows functions to use the element type separately, which you can see with the second argument: `f func(E) bool`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use reflection. I wrote this function for a project, feel free to use it:

```
// InSlice returns true if value is in slice
func InSlice(value, slice interface{}) bool {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(slice).Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Ptr:
        values := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(slice))
        if values.Len() == 0 {
            return false
        }

        val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(value))

        if val.Kind() != values.Index(0).Kind() {
            return false
        }

        for i := 0; i < values.Len(); i++ {
            if reflect.DeepEqual(values.Index(i).Interface(), val.Interface()) {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: maybe show how to use it? I guess afterwards you have to cast it to the desired type?

Answer (score 3):

if you have predefined type like `[]int` or `[]string` and do not want to convert to `[]interface{}` see this working sample code (without using `reflect`):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func find(s []int, f func(int) bool) int {
    for i, item := range s {
        if f(item) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
func findString(s []string, f func(string) bool) int {
    for i, item := range s {
        if f(item) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func main() {
    s := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    fmt.Println(find(s, func(a int) bool { return a == 5 })) //5

    strs := []string{"A", "B", "C"}
    fmt.Println(findString(strs, func(a string) bool { return a == "B" })) //1
}
```

or you may use `reflect`,like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func find(slice interface{}, f func(interface{}) bool) int {
    switch reflect.TypeOf(slice).Kind() {
    case reflect.Slice:
        values := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(slice))
        for i := 0; i < values.Len(); i++ {
            if f(values.Index(i).Interface()) {
                return i
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func main() {
    a := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    fmt.Println(find(a, func(i interface{}) bool { return i == 5 })) //5

    b := []string{"A", "B", "C"}
    fmt.Println(find(b, func(i interface{}) bool { return i == "B" })) //1
}
```

output:

```
5
1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I already have 2 arrays: a := A[]{} and b := B[]{} 
how does what you suggest work in that case? find(a, fa)  and find(b, fb) cannot be called. (I want just 1 find function to avoid to duplicate it)

Comment: thanks, but that's now the answer above :) but thanks for the hard work, I +1. If you want you can keep just the last part in your answer, it is the best and makes things more readbale

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you want to have slice of arbitrary values and use that sort of `find` function and have the possibility of standard `[]` reslicing, maybe the best way is to encapsulate your `interface{}` with another struct

```
type proxy struct {
    val interface{}
}
```

and use

```
func find(s []proxy , f func(proxy)bool) int {}
```

and have the `f` function deal with `interface{}` comparison / type casting.

Comment: Thanks but this forces me to copy my array into []proxy. but maybe worth it I have to see

Comment: I don't understand this solution. Why is `[]proxy` better than `[]interface{}`?

Comment: @PaulHankin Go doesn't compile when you pass in []A when you have an []inteface{} argument

Comment: Nor does is compile if you pass in []A when you have a []proxy argument. In both cases one needs to wrap the underlying data in a common type -- this answer suggests `proxy`, but I don't see why that's better than just using `interface{}`. Am I missing something?

Comment: here is a [link](https://play.golang.org/p/l49fOsECDt) for clarification