# In Go, how do I pass a slice of interface to something that expects slice of a different compatible interface?

Tags: go

I have two interfaces, `A` and `B`. It happens that `A` includes `B`. Finally, I have a concrete implementation of `A` (call it `Impl`), which, by definition, also implements `B`.

For example:

```
type A interface {
    Close() error
    Read(b []byte) (int, error)
}

type Impl struct {}
func (I Impl) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println("In read!")
    return 10, nil
}
func (I Impl) Close() error {
    fmt.Println("I am here!")
    return nil
}
```

Since `A` requires `Read()`, and `Impl` implements `A`, it also satisfies `io.Reader`.

If I try to pass individual items across functions, it works fine. But if I try slices of `A` to functions expecting `io.Reader`, it fails.

Example:

```
func single(r io.Reader) {
    fmt.Println("in single")
}
func slice(r []io.Reader) {
    fmt.Println("in slice")
}
im := &Impl{}

// works
single(im)

// FAILS!
list := []A{t}
slice(list)
```

If I can pass an `A` to `single(r io.Reader)`, why can I not pass `[]A` to `slice(r []io.Reader)`, and how would I correct it?

Actual implementation at https://play.golang.org/p/QOREQJTQhD just uncomment the last two lines in `main()` and the error shows:

```
main.go:38: cannot use list (type []A) as type []io.Reader in argument to slice
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I kind of asked something similar here
[In Go, how can I make a generic function with slices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525874/in-go-how-can-i-make-a-generic-function-with-slices)

Sadly, this is definitely a weakness in Go. The only way for you to go around this is to make a new slice of type []io.Reader with elements from []A

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I came across your question when I was trying to figure this out, but wondered if it is the same thing. I am not looking for generics (although you could argue that my `A` and `io.Reader` are just specialized cases of your `interface` generic), but rather to pass in `[]A` (whose implementations must implement `io.Reader`) to a function that expects `[]io.Reader`. I can pass `A` to a function that expects `io.Reader`, so why not the slice as well?

Comment: @deitch from my understanding of Go, a slice is a very special case. You can do a.(io.Reader) but not []a.([]io.Reader), they are unconvertible and Go is strongly typed

Comment: Reading through your other question, and the one flagged above, I was able to understand it. But you are right, and @icza is wrong in that (a) this isn't an exact duplicate (it has the same underlying principles, but not exactly the same question) and (b) this most certainly *is* a weakness.

Comment: I think the -1 is hateful and should really be given to people who don't put effort in writing their question, etc. I have upvoted you to balance for that

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, but most especially appreciate your help.